# Saving credentials with google one tap showing save dialog even credentials are same

Tags: android, google-identity, google-one-tap

I am using google one tap for sign in purpose with username-password,
And saving the credentials using Google one tap as described in this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/save-passwords).

But getting an issue, I am seeing save dialog even login credentials are same to earlier saved one.
Lets say Initially I logged in using username-> test1@g.m   password- 12345 and save those to google using one tap save dialog.
Now I gets logout and try to login with same account username-> test1@g.m   password- 12345 and try to save them using google one tap so I suppose to not to see save dialog, but it visible.